# How does a player's fide rating change calculated for previous month's rating even in the next month

Tags: fide, rating, tournament, elo, tournament-directors

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/40524/23596) asked some time back to which I didn't quite understand the given answer.

I'll take an example
A certain player had [rating 2422 on Sep 2022](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/9953698/chart) according to the chart
But gained [+94 rating](https://ratings.fide.com/calculations.phtml?id_number=9953698&period=2022-10-01&rating=0) and therefore in the next month rated 2500+. Also note that after 2400 K-factor becomes 10. But when looking at the `Standard Ratings October 2022` link can see that the +94 was calculated as if the player was a 2213 rated player (rating before becoming a 2422 player so the previous month's rating). This is seen in the `ro = 2213` and `K = 40` in the table.

How is the `ro` not **2422** and `K` not **10**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tournament started on August 26th, so August ratings were used to calculate rating changes. Since the event was still ongoing by September 1st, the results weren't taken into account until the following list (computed on October 1st).

Since all rating changes for a single tournament are calculated assuming no rating changes have occured, the whole tournament is computed as if the player had a rating of 2213, rather than 2213 for the games layed in August and 2422 for the ones played in September.

Comment: "So, in theory games submitted for rating in the last 3 days of the month may end up being rated in the next month's list in which case they will use the player's new rating from the current month." this was on [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/40524/23596). i got confused doesn't this mean 2422 should be considered or maybe i didn't understand properly since I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: @cmgchess in this case it wouldn't matter since the games wouldn't be submitted until the end of the tournament either way. But yes, if the tournament had ended on, say, August 30th, the same thing would have happened